# Template with asymmetric border

Tags: templates

it's the first time I use latex and I would like to create a document [like this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i5Q_hiwEe4k4n32fIjsxzKfdXKF4e6F8).

I looked for a template already done on different sites (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/, https://www.latextemplates.com/, https://it.sharelatex.com/templates) that are similar to what I would like but I didn't find anything.

The peculiarity of my example is that it has different border for even and odd pages and some images can be inserted in the right/left border.

Can someone tell me a similar template?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at `tufte-book`.